# Why subject emits empty Array after change component RXjs Angular 2+

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have an issue because I don't understand why `Subject` emits empty data.
I have a base from where I get data to a Service like this:

```
 eventChanged = new Subject<any>(); 

 constructor(private http: HttpClient) { 
     this.http.get<Event[]>(this.baseUrl)
       .subscribe(events => { 
          this.events = events
          this.eventChanged.next(this.events.slice());
       });
      }
  getEvents(): Observable<any> {
    return this.eventChanged.asObservable();
  }
```

And my components Observe that Subject in `ngOnInit()`

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.dataService.getEvents()
    .subscribe(
    (events) => {
      this.events = events;      
    });       
  }
```

It works on first time I "construct" a service with the component constructor.

```
constructor(private dataService: EventListService) { }
```

But when I change view component then back to him I receive empty `this.events`

I check that EventService have "Events[]" in his variable, so I dont know why Subject emits or not emit any values. Any one know what is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After `constructor` in your service is called it fetches data and emits them through subject and saves them in `events` property.

In `ngOnInit` you are probably already subscribed to that `Subject` therefore you receive those data. But that's the last moment when these are emitted (because `constructor` of the service is not called again).

Although you are trying to save data in `events` property. You dont use them anywhere.

If you want to persist your data in a service and be able to get them anytime. You could use `BehaviorSubject` which remembers the last value.

```
eventChanged = new BehaviorSubject<any>([]); 

constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  this.refetch();
}

getEvents(): Observable<any> {
  return this.eventChanged.asObservable();
}

refetch(): void {
  this.http.get<Event[]>(this.baseUrl)
    .subscribe(events => 
       this.eventChanged.next(events);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for explanation.